# Power calculations for a mixed model using simr

Tags: r, mixed-model, simulation, statistical-power

I'm trying to conduct a power calculation for a mixed effect model I built using lmer.
I already have some pilot data, so I have an idea of the estimated effect size, but what I'd like to know is what my power will be at different sample sizes.

I'd like to be able to generate a graph (ie a powercurve) showing my power at different sample sizes.

Here's an example of what I've tried so far:

```
library(simr)
set.seed(1234)
smaller.df <- data.frame(
  aid <- rep(1:10, 200),
  subj <- rep(1:200, each=10),
  x = sample(1:6, 2000, replace = T),
  m = sample(1:3, 2000, replace = T),
  y = rnorm(2000)
)

model.of.interest2 <- lmer(y ~ x*m + (1|subj), data=smaller.df)

powerSim(model.of.interest2, nsim=100, test = fcompare(y~x))

pwr1 <- powerCurve(model.of.interest2, nsim=100, along = "subj", test = fcompare(y~x))
plot(pwr1)
```

However, no matter how I change the parameters, it generates the same graph and and tells me that I either have 0% or 100% power.

For example, I can adjust the sample size from having 200 subjects (ie 2000 rows) to 10 or 20 subjects (100 or 200 rows) and I get the same.

I can insert some effects (based on effect sizes from my pilot data):

```
fixef(model.of.interest2)['x'] <- .45
fixef(model.of.interest2)['m'] <- 1.41
fixef(model.of.interest2)['x:m'] <- .17
```

But then when I run the powerCurve code, the line just jumps straight up from 0 to 100%.

I've tried generating different aspects of the model, but no matter what I do, I don't get a "curve".

I'm at a loss for how to generate informative information about sample size with a simple mixed model.

Comment: What is the hypothesis you want to test ? Your model is `lmer(y ~ x*m + (1|subj), ...` so presumably your research question is related to the fixed effects for `x`, `m` and/or their interaction ?

Comment: @RobertLong This is based on a study where I'm testing the interaction between two variables similar to `x` and `m`. This is a simplified version, though (ie I already have data) but really I'm just interested in how I can calculate power for a specific effect size at different sample sizes.